# VB.NET “not supported Exception”?

Tags: vb.net, notsupportedexception

Dose anybody know how i can get around this  “not supported Exception”?

```
'Amends label2 to file name as text (works in conjunction with PART 00-AB form1)...
    Label2.Text = "Project: " & Form1.Label5.Text & " could not be found"

    'sugesting other related files in the folder...
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("v:\" & Label2.Text & "\Tekeningen\Tekenwerk De Mar\Definitief\" & Label2.Text & ".PDF")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

    For Each dra In diar1
        If System.IO.Path.GetExtension(dra.Name).ToLower() = "pdf" Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well which line is throwing the exception? (And what's the context here - web app? WinForms?)

Comment: oops  Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("v:\" & Label2.Text & "\Tekeningen\Tekenwerk De Mar\Definitief\" & Label2.Text & ".PDF") its a winform

Comment: You really have a directory with a .pdf extension?

Answer (score 2):

It means that the path you given is not supported by the class `DirectoryInfo`. I has to be a directory, and it seems that you are trying to use a PDF file.

Maybe you wanted something like this:

```
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("v:\" & Label2.Text & "\Tekeningen\Tekenwerk De Mar\Definitief\")
```

And, by the way, you could use this to get only PDF files in a faster way without need to check all the files on the folder:

```
DIm diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.pdf")
```